# Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource

Tags: amazon-ecs, liquibase

Hi I am running my liquibase scripts via ECS task. However getting below error.

> 2024-01-16T19:24:33,964 ERROR [main] SpringApplication id= marker= - Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:

it also says.

> 1 change sets check sum

When I am running the script via DB console it works fine.

```
ALTER TABLE public.t_universalkey ALTER COLUMN qid TYPE character varying (20);

ALTER TABLE public.t_universalkey_changelog ALTER COLUMN qid TYPE character varying (20);
```

However via liquibase scripts it fails.

Comment: It looks like you did not paste the full validation error - please edit your question and provide the full error text. Also, never run two independent changes in a single changeset.